# After uploading to server, Image::make not working

Tags: laravel, server, intervention

When I run the project on my server, there is no problem, everything is ok. But after uploaded to the server there is a problem in `Image::make()` line.

```
try{
    $photo = Image::make($request->photo)->fit(300, 300);
    $photo_name = Str::slug($user->name, '-')."-".Str::slug($user->surname, '-')."-photo-".now()->format('Y-m-d-H-i-s')."-300x300.".$request->photo->extension();
    $photo_path='files/user/picture/'.$photo_name;
    $photo->save($photo_path);
}
catch (\Exception $e){
    report($e);
    return response([
        'error' => $e,
        'message' => 'Photo could not uploaded'
    ],Response::HTTP_NOT_IMPLEMENTED);
}
```

And I get this error:

```
{
   "error": [],
   "message": "Photo could not uploaded"
}
```

pip.ini:

```
memory_limit = 350M
post_max_size = 300M
upload_max_filesize = 300M
```

But, if change source code like that, there is no problem, image is uploading.

```
try{
    $photo = $request->photo;
    $photo_name = Str::slug($user->name, '-')."-".Str::slug($user->surname, '-')."-photo-".now()->format('Y-m-d-H-i-s')."-300x300.".$request->photo->extension();
    $photo_public_path = public_path('files/user/picture/');
    $photo_path = 'files/user/picture/'.$photo_name;
    $photo->move($photo_public_path, $photo_name);

}
catch (\Exception $e){
    report($e);
    return response([
        'error' => $e,
        'message' => 'Photo could not uploaded'
    ],Response::HTTP_NOT_IMPLEMENTED);
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$request->file('photo')`? Can you try `Image::make($request->file('photo')->getRealPath())->fit(300, 300);`

Comment: Not helped. Same problem...